# Is it possible to init an app with higher priority?

Tags: ios, multithreading, process, pthreads

I have an app on iOS and generate a MIDI clock in a realtime pthread. If I switch between the app and others some times the clock is no more accurate -> so my idea: increase the priority/nice value may be will fix that problem. But how can i change the priority from my code on iOS?

Comment: Thankfully no, it is not possible for apps to be given a higher priority over other apps.

Comment: But it should be possible. If you use e.g. SystemMonitor you will find apps and processes with higher priority (e.g. Launchkey a Novation app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use MIDI packet lists, which are an iOS internal mechanism for sending MIDI data with accurate timestamps, and it's ridiculously accurate in pretty much any situation (I've developed a MIDI sequencer for iOS using these).

Answer (score 0):

The NSThread class has a [`setPriorityLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/setThreadPriority%3a) method or you could you use the GCD high priority queue [`dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dispatch_get_global_queue.3.html).

I would be surprised if it made much different WRT timing, however.

Comment: This just changes the priority of the thread within the application and has no effect whatsoever on scheduling vs. other applications, which is the OP's question.

Comment: @David And you're sure that thread scheduling is done on a per-process basis (i.e. the thread priority only matters within a *that* process)?

Comment: Relatively certain, yes.  Rereading the NSThread documentation doesn't really add any information on the topic, but historically that's been the case with most unices I've worked with.  With kernel level threads implemented as mach threads, it's possible that's changed, but I wouldn't really think so.  No way I'd want my note application to raise it's own priority to the maximum and starve out my phone application.

Comment: Well nobody is talking about staving; the kernel would be broken if it allowed that, however I think without studying the kernel scheduling code there's no way to know for sure what effect the thread priority has globally.  However I don't condone the raising the thread priorities in order to make something work, so I don't really care that much; I just wanted to know if your comment was as authoritative as it sounded.